# Elements on JPanel not appearing

Tags: java, swing

I'm fairly new to GUI programming with swing and am having what I'm sure is a noob problem.

I've created a JFrame with a JPanel inside of it. Then I'm trying to add a JLabel for each element in an array. The problem is that the elements are not appearing on the panel. I've checked to make sure that the array elements are registering using a println statement, so that's not the problem. I'm guessing that I'm missing a statement somewhere... please advise.

Here's my code:

```
public class MazeFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Maze m;
    /**
     * Creates new form MazeFrame
     */
    public MazeFrame(Maze m) {
        this.m = m;
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        add(pan);
        setVisible(true);
        // pan.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(m.width, m.height));

        for (int curr = 0; curr < m.height; curr++){
            for (Cell c: m.maze[curr]){
                JLabel lab = new JLabel();
                switch (c.state){
                    case border:
                        lab.setBackground(Color.black);
                        System.out.println("addedborder");
                        break;
                    case wall:
                        lab.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                        System.out.println("addedwall");
                        break;
                    case open: 
                        lab.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                        System.out.println("addedopen");
                        break;
                    case travelled: 
                        lab.setBackground(Color.RED);             
                }
                lab.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                lab.setVisible(true);               
                pan.add(lab);
                //   System.out.println("added");
            }
        }
        pan.revalidate();
        pan.repaint();
    }
}
```

Here's the maze class:

```
package robots;

import java.util.Random;


public class Maze {
    public Cell[][] maze;
    final int width;
    final int height;  

    public Maze(){
        width = 20;
        height = 20;
        maze = new Cell[width][height];
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++){
                maze[row][col] = new Cell(row, col);
            }
        }

        // set borders
        for (int curr = 0; curr < height; curr++) {
            maze[0][curr].setState("border");
            maze[curr][0].setState("border");
            maze[height - 1][curr].setState("border");
            maze[curr][width - 1].setState("border");
        }

        // initially mark all cells as walls
        for (int row = 1; row < height - 1; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < width - 1; col++) {
                maze[row][col].setState("wall");
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean isValidTurn(int row, int col) {
        if (row >= 0 && col < width && col > 0 && 
                    row < 20 && (!this.maze[row][col].getState().matches("open"))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void makeRoute() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int row = 0;
        int col = r.nextInt(width);
        maze[row][col].setState("open");
        row = row+1;
        maze[row][col].setState("open");

        // System.out.println(this);
        while (row < (this.height - 1)) {
            // Assuming the mouse moves in only 3 directions left right or down
            // in the maze. 0 indicates left turn 1 indicates right turn and
            // 2 indicates down movement in the maze.
            int nextDir = r.nextInt(3);
            switch (nextDir) {
                case 0: // left turn
                    if (this.isValidTurn(row, (col - 1))) {
                        --col;
                        this.maze[row][col].setState("open");
                    }
                    break;
                case 1: // right turn
                    if (this.isValidTurn(row, (col + 1))) {
                        ++col;
                        this.maze[row][col].setState("open");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: // down movement
                    ++row;
                    this.maze[row][col].setState("open");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("turn : " + nextDir);
            // System.out.println(this);
        }
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}

class Cell {
    int row;
    int col;
    int above, below, toLeft, toRight;
    enum state {border, wall, open, travelled};
    state state;

    public Cell(int row, int col){
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        above = row + 1;
        below = row -1;
        toLeft = col -1;
        toRight = col +1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String out = new String();
        if (state == state.border) {
            out = "0";
        }
        if (state == state.wall) {
            out = "#";
        }
        if (state == state.open) {
            out = ".";
        }
        if (state == state.open) {
            out = "-";
        }     
        return out;
    }

    public void setState(String toSet){
        switch (toSet){
            case "border":
                state = state.border;
                break;
            case "wall": 
                state = state.wall;
                break;
            case "open": 
                state = state.open;
                break;
            case "travelled": 
                state = state.travelled;
                break;
        }
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state.toString();
    }
}
```

But, as I said, I know that the maze class works fine, because it outputs to the console  perfectly when I run it. Also, the println statements in the MazeFrame class show that each cell is registering with its respective state.

Comment: Try moving `setVisible(true)` so it appears at the end of the constructor

Comment: just tried it, still have the same problem...

Comment: Please post your Maze class and Cell class too

Comment: @drewmore4 i try to dig in your code but i cant find the error. I have to debug in it. please send me the class containing the main method. festus@tamakloe.de (If you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments in the code:

```
public class MazeFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Maze m;
    /**
     * Creates new form MazeFrame
     */
    public MazeFrame(Maze m) {
        this.m = m;
//  Don't manually set the size of a frame. Let the preferred size of you components determine the size. 
// This is done by invoking pack() after all components have been added to the frame.
//        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); 
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        add(pan);
//        setVisible(true); // do after all components added.
        // pan.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(m.width, m.height));

        for (int curr = 0; curr < m.height; curr++){
            for (Cell c: m.maze[curr]){
                JLabel lab = new JLabel();
                lab.setOpaque(true); // as suggested by MadProgrammer
                switch (c.state){
                    case border:
                        lab.setBackground(Color.black);
                        System.out.println("addedborder");
                        break;
                    case wall:
                        lab.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                        System.out.println("addedwall");
                        break;
                    case open: 
                        lab.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                        System.out.println("addedopen");
                        break;
                    case travelled: 
                        lab.setBackground(Color.RED);             
                }
// Set the preferred size so layout managers can do there job
//                lab.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                lab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
// Not required. This is the default for all components except top level containers like JFrame, JDialog
//                lab.setVisible(true);               
                pan.add(lab);
                //   System.out.println("added");
            }
        }
//  No neeed to revalidate or repaint because the frame is not visible yet
//        pan.revalidate();
//        pan.repaint();
        pack(); // let the layout manager determine the size of the frame
        setVisible(); // show the frame
    }
}
```

Note: Normally you don't even need to set the preferred size of a component because each component has a preferred size. But in this case you didn't add text or an Icon to the label so it won't have a preferred size.

Answer (score 3):

As i know you should call revalidate/repaint when you add components to any visible container, so you could move your setVisible & adding panel to frame to last statement:

```
// update panel
pan.revalidate();
pan.repaint();

// adding panel to frame
this.add(pan);
this.pack();
this.setVisible(true);
```

the other thing you don't need to call JLabel.setVisible(true) because its the default, also to change the background of JLabel you need to add (because its transparent by default):

```
lab.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: I did all of those things (moved revalidate/repaint to the bottom, added setOpaque(true), and still I have the same result

Comment: make sure you call pack() before setvisible.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get something to work (as to if it's correct is another matter)

[image]

Basically all I did (apart from moving `setVisible` to the end of the constructor) was make the `lab` opaque...

```
public TestMaze(Maze m) {
    this.m = m;
    setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    add(pan);
    pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(m.width, m.height));

    for (int curr = 0; curr < m.height; curr++) {
        for (Cell c : m.maze[curr]) {
            JLabel lab = new JLabel();
            lab.setOpaque(true); // <-- Add me...
            switch (c.state) {
                case border:
                    lab.setBackground(Color.black);
                    break;
                case wall:
                    lab.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    break;
                case open:
                    lab.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    break;
                case travelled:
                    lab.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            lab.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            lab.setVisible(true);
            pan.add(lab);
            //   System.out.println("added");
        }
    }
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: +1 for setOpaque(). I think all Swing components (except JLabel and JComponent) are opaque by default, so this is an exception.